# Swift Date Picker String to NSDate conversion reduced by 1 year

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am having problem when I am converting a date String fetched from datePicker to NSDate.

For example, if I select date in the date picker as 23/12/1990 and then convert it to NSDate, the result is different. It shows 1989-12-23 23:00:00 UTC.

When I make a POST request, I need to send the date as three strings - one for day, one for month and other for year.
So for my POST request, I am converting my NSDate to String again.
Which gives result as 1989-12-24

I can not avoid doing this because in my Model, the dateOfBirth is set as NSDate, which if I change, is going to create many other issues.

Finally, after the POST request is successful, and I get my strings for day, month and year... I have to set it as NSDate again. Which is giving result as - 1989-12-24 - the same as the string I converted from NSDate.

Can anyone help me resolving this issue?

**Here is my code when I click SAVE in my Form** -

```
        var birthDate: NSDate?

        if let dateOfBirthText = dateOfBirth.text {
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
            birthDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateOfBirthText)
        }
```

**Here is my code when I am converting this NSDate to String during POST request**

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(userPersonalData.dateOfBirth!)

            let individualDateComponents = dateString.componentsSeparatedByString("-")
            let dobYear = "\(individualDateComponents[0])"
            let dobMonth = "\(individualDateComponents[1])"
            let dobDay = "\(individualDateComponents[2])"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that the result is `1989-12-23 23:00:00 UTC`. That means you want to work with dates in *UTC*. Therefore you have to set the timezone of the picker to UTC, too.

And everywhere where you want to avoid the time zone differences...:

```
let utcTimeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let datePicker: UIDatePicker = ...
datePicker.timeZone = utcTimeZone

let posixLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = posixLocale //you should really use this when encoding dates for API
formatter.timeZone = utcTimeZone
```

Also make sure to use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`.

Comment: The problem is the use of `YYYY`. This question comes up every year.

Comment: @rmaddy I think both problems are there.

Comment: @Sulthan: thank you.. this works now but when I populate the picker view for my textField, it shows one day less than my dateOfBirth String. Sorry for the dumb question. I am just not able to figure out where I am doing wrong

Comment: @Sulthan@rmaddy Thanks for saving my life